# Android + setOnClickListener sets setClickable to true by default?

Tags: android

I have a ButtonView in an xml layout and set the focusable/clickable attributes to false.  I'm attempting to prevent click events on the ButtonView until a flag is set to true.  Anyway, this works fine until I write the setOnClickListner code on the ButtonView.  It seems to automatically set setClickable() to true.  Is there a way to prevent this, or is this the default behavior?  I figured I could set the listener at any time, and ignore events until I set setClickable() on the Button. Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Snicolas said.

You can disable the button for that purpose. Then no callback on the `setOCL()` will be triggered when your button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the additional response! Using "setEnabled()" was the ticket!

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)

This behavior is documented.

> Register a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked. **If this view is not clickable, it becomes clickable.**

Answer (score 0):

since you already have the option of setting **setClickable()** at your disposal.

i assume you are wondering about any best practice.

just curious, will not making the button **disabled** be more **intuitive** to the user about the situation.